# Blank output in array looping in react native

Tags: arrays, loops, react-native

My output of following code is blank. I am not able to figure it out why question is not printed or even answer buttons.

Tried checking various answers and changing call methods. No error is shown in code.

```
const datas = [
        {
          id: 1,
          text: "Question 1",
          ans: [
            {
              id: 1,
              name: "Ans 1",
            },
            {
              id: 2,
              name: "Ans 2",
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          text: "Question 2",
          ans: [
            {
              id: 1,
              name: "Ans 1",
            },
            {
              id: 2,
              name: "Ans 2",
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          text: "Question 3",
          ans: [
            {
              id: 1,
              name: "Ans 1",
            },
            {
              id: 2,
              name: "Ans 2",
            }
          ]
        }
        ]
      ;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text> Question 1</Text>
        <View style={styles.cardContainer}>
          <View style={styles.card}>
            {datas.map((data) => {
              <Text style={styles.quesText}> {data.text} </ Text>
                  { data.ans.map((answ) => {
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.choiceButton} onPress={ () => this.props.navigation.navigate('Quiz')}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{answ.name}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  })}
              })}
              </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    )

}}
```

It should show:
Question 1

and two buttons with Ans 1 and Ans 2

Comment: What happens when you limit it to just {datas.map((data) => "Test"} ? Are you getting any output at all? If not, then the issue is outside of the mapping function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both your `map` usages you are not returning anything. So, simply add a `return` for each content. Also note that you can't return multiple children, instead wrap them in a `<View>` to achieve your objective. Here you have the correct code:

```
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text> Question 1</Text>
    <View style={styles.cardContainer}>
      <View style={styles.card}>
        {datas.map(data => {
          return (
            <View>
              <Text style={styles.quesText}>{data.text}</Text>
              {data.ans.map(answ => {
                return (
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    style={styles.choiceButton}
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Quiz')}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{answ.name}</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                );
              })}
            </View>
          );
        })}
      </View>
    </View>
  </View>
);
```

Comment: Yes, I was missing return.